# C++ - Struct in separate file

Tags: c++, struct, lnk2005

I'm using MVS 2013 and I wrote struct in file ListStruct.h. During linking I'm getting error LNK2005:

```
error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall ListStruct::ListStruct(void)" (??0ListStruct@@QAE@XZ) already defined in projekt1.obj
```

Now - part of ListStruct.h

```
#ifndef _LISTSTRUCT_H_
#define _LISTSTRUCT_H_

#include "stdafx.h"

struct ListStruct{
    Member *head;                       //wskaznik na poczatek listy
    Member *tail;                       //wskaznik na koniec listy
    void AddMember(int value);
    void RemoveMember(int value);
    void Display();
    ListStruct();
};
#endif
```

Part of my main:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ListStruct *base = new ListStruct;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to create ListStruct.cpp file? How it supposed to look like?

Comment: _"Part of my main"_ Did you redefine the `ListStruct` constructor there? Where did you put the implementation, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in header ListStruct.h in the part that you did not show there is a definition of constructor

```
ListStruct();
```

As this header is included in more than one module then the linker issues  error that the constructor is already defined.

Either you should define the constructor only in one module or define it with function specifier `inline` in the header.

Comment: Yes, I have constructor. But there is only "head = 0;". How that constructor can be already defined? Where?